# How to add clickable <a> tag SVG component in NextJS 13?

Tags: html, reactjs, web, svg, next.js

Load a simple svg on my NextJs v13 using SVGR:

```
<svg height='50'>
  <a href='#'><text x='0' y='20'>click in svg</text> </a>
</svg>
```

```
import './globals.css'
import Vercel from '../public/vercel.svg'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
      <div>
        Hello World
        <Vercel  />
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

this is my webpack config in next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    webpack(config) {
        // Configures webpack to handle SVG files with SVGR. SVGR optimizes and transforms SVG files
        // into React components. See https://react-svgr.com/docs/next/

        // Grab the existing rule that handles SVG imports
        // @ts-ignore - this is a private property that is not typed
        const fileLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find((rule) => rule.test?.test?.('.svg'));

        config.module.rules.push(
            // Reapply the existing rule, but only for svg imports ending in ?url
            {
                ...fileLoaderRule,
                test: /\.svg$/i,
                resourceQuery: /url/, // *.svg?url
            },
            // Convert all other *.svg imports to React components
            {
                test: /\.svg$/i,
                issuer: fileLoaderRule.issuer,
                resourceQuery: { not: [...fileLoaderRule.resourceQuery.not, /url/] }, // exclude if *.svg?url
                use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
            }
        );

        // Modify the file loader rule to ignore *.svg, since we have it handled now.
        fileLoaderRule.exclude = /\.svg$/i;

        return config;
    },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

[result](https://ibb.co/c3gXdrV)

the link is not clickable, looks like NextJs can't read  tag inside svg.
Or any way NextJS can render pure html?

I want to achieve [clickable map](https://rufai.github.io/buildingx/TourAfrique/) using NextJS with SVGR.

NextJS Version: Next.js v13.4.2
SVGR Version: "^8.1.0"

Answer (score 0):

It's solved now.

need to add:

```
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
```

and this to  tag:

```
 xlink:href
```

Comment: Hi. I know that you solved the issue, but if somebody else should learn from from this it would be a good idea to explain how this helped. And show how the namespace should be placed into the code.